# installing 11-40T Sunrace cassette with Sram Rival 22

Tags: cassette, sram

I'm trying to build up a hillclimb bike (Mt. Washington) - current set-up is OK, but I could use the help AND don't care about temporarily losing the use of my big chain ring.  Current set-up (all SRAM Rival 22):

- 50/34 crankset
- 11-32 cassette
- mid-length rear derailleur

Seems like the conversion should be possible with Sunrace CSMX8 cassette (11-40T, 11-speed), the Wolftooth derailleur hanger extension, and a SRAM PC-1130 chain.

Assuming this is possible, are there pitfalls to consider?  Other recommended parts?

**RESULTS**
*For those of you who arrive in this rather obscure location wondering about a similar set-up, I made the change described above and disabled the front derailleur (per @Argenti Apparatus's suggestion) and it worked out beautifully - so far, shifts as well as or better than the standard set-up with the SRAM cassette...*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

SRAM Rival 22 mid-cage derailleurs work with 11-28 to 11-32 cassettes. Rival 22 cranks come in 52/36,  50/34 and 46/36 so I'm guessing the total capacity is 
(32-11) + (50-34) = 37.

If you will be running as pseudo 1x setup by not using the big ring, you will have plenty of capacity in the rear for a 11-40 cassette. Derailleur hanger extensions do apparently work but you may find you have some shifting issues.

Consider disabling the front derailleur, changing to the big ring by mistake could wreck the rear derailleur.

Answer (score 0):

The difference (capacity) between large-large and small-small combinations for your planned setup is quite large. 50+40 - 34+11 = 67. I can’t find capacity numbers for the SRAM derailleurs but I doubt the Rival 22 can properly tension the chain in all combinations.

However, you could use an SRAM Rival 1 long cage rear derailleur. It should be compatible with the Rival 22 shifters (both have the 1:1 “exact actuation” pull ratio) and is even rated for 10-42 cassettes so you don’t need the Wolftooth.

A disadvantage of the 11-40 cassette are [the big steps](http://ritzelrechner.de/?GR=DERS&KB=34&RZ=11,13,15,17,19,21,24,28,32,36,40&UF=2125&TF=90&SL=2.6&UN=KMH&DV=teeth) between gears, but I guess you are aware of that.

Comment: I'm unconcerned about this set-up working in the large chainring (this is a temporary set-up for hill-climbing) - does that fact affect the capacity issue you raised?  How well would a Rival1 derailleur work with a 2x set-up (even if only using the small/34T chainring)?

Comment: capacity calculation above isn't right.
(50-34)+(40-11)=45. [Normal recommended capacity would be (50-34)+(32-11)=37.] Perhaps still too much for Rival 22 RD, but not as bad as suggested.

Comment: It has been suggested that your calculation 50+40 - 34+11 = 67 should be (50-34)+(40-11)=45, I'm just commenting it for your attention as new contributor can't make comments yet